# Business Objects Error

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects

While running Business Objects reports,One of the cell value getting as '#ERROR'.

Actually what i am doing is ,I am constructing measuring object from two individual db fields.

and finally adding both of these two field values using "ToNumber" and "+".

Any hints how to solve this issue and is anyway to debug the code in BO.

Regards,

Chaitu

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, When you are constructing a measure object, you are saving the numeric value in the object. Secondly, you cannot use ToNumber, as it should always be a number. Thidly, All the measure objects should use aggregate functions. This will ensure that the aggregation happens at the database for the selected dimensions.

Debugging code is a pain in BO, specially if you have a lengthy code written. You can always verify the code for syntactical correctness, and its better to use a text editor like Notepad and then paste the code over there.

Answer (score 0):

debung code is a pain, the best way is to copy the code to Notepad++ and verify the code, to avoid this issue, what I'm doing is to create a measure object in the universe, and with this I can use it in the cell.